# Accessing private keys in Hyperledger Fabric 2.0 from a webclient using javascript?

Tags: node.js, hyperledger-fabric

I am interested to register a user from a web client and was wondering about converting the code below. The current setup uses a wallet stored on a server accessed via nodejs. But what if I access this entirely from a webclient. Can I use the API calls for hyperledger fabric 2.0 directly in a webclient and access the private key on a client device?

Here is the nodejs example -

```
const { Wallets } = require('fabric-network');
const FabricCAServices = require('fabric-ca-client');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

async function main() {
    try {
        // load the network configuration
        const ccpPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '..', '..', 'test-network', 'organizations', 'peerOrganizations', 'org1.example.com', 'connecti
on-org1.json');
     //   const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath, 'utf8'));
        const ccpPath1 = "./fabric-samples/test-network/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/connection-org1.json";
        const ccp = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(ccpPath1, 'utf8'));


        // Create a new CA client for interacting with the CA.
        const caURL = ccp.certificateAuthorities['ca.org1.example.com'].url;
        const ca = new FabricCAServices(caURL);

        // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities.
        const walletPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'wallet');
        const wallet = await Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletPath);
        console.log(`Wallet path: ${walletPath}`);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to connect to the fabric node from a client(In this case your Node JS code), You need to have an identity (a certificate and private key to prove the certificate belongs you), that the node you are connecting to recognizes. So basically without a private key and a certificate you cannot connect to a fabric node.
If you have access to your organization admin's private key and certificate, You can use these to load an identity to a Wallet. The Wallet can be In-Memory, File System or Couch DB wallet as required by you.

```js
const identity: X509Identity = {
    credentials: {
        certificate: 'PEM format certificate string',
        privateKey: 'PEM format private key string',
    },
    mspId: 'org1',
    type: 'X.509',
};
await wallet.put('admin.org1', identity);
```

You can now use this admin identity to connect to the org CA and request to register and enroll more users as required.

You can also use a HSM provider with the wallet.

Read more [here](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-sdk-node/release-2.2/tutorial-wallet.html)